# Fetching only head of a single branch and pushing to an empty repo on Git

Tags: git

I have a repo with my codebase, and each project inherits this codebase.
It has it's submodules on it and everything works fine.

When I start a new project from scratch, how is supposed to be cloning this repo (only the master branch) and only the HEAD (since I don't want each project have a lot of commits of the base).

I tried:

```
    git init
    git remote add -t origin URLtoProjectRepo
    git remote add -t codebase URLtoMainCodeBase
    git pull codebase master --depth=1
```

When I try to push this to the project repo I get:

```
    [remote rejected] master -> master (missing necessary objects)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'ProjectURL'
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot push an incomplete history, but making a no-history commit is easy:

```
git fetch --depth=1 git://wherever master
git checkout -B master $(git cat-file -p FETCH_HEAD|git commit-tree FETCH_HEAD^{tree})
```

will give you a fairly ugly commit message that includes the original history links as text; plopping `|sed 1,/^$/d` in there will strip even the documentary links to the past.

Comment: :-) the tic was nice, the thanks actually boosted my mood.  back atcha :-)

Comment: can you please give me advice? I'm using this now, and when I try to push my project code to its own repo, I get this error:
    error: Could not read 088acd304e40357f1a7a52d9deda2bd6b5d295de
    fatal: revision walk setup failed

Comment: That's pretty much guaranteed to be unrelated to this, ask it as a separate question please, and include details? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to solve. I have a base repository which is essentially the core code for many other projects. The other projects first pull the core repository then check that into the new project repository. By doing that, any time changes are made to the core repo we can easily merge the changes into our projects. Being new to git, this is the result of what I learned while researching this. I took this out of a perl script I use to automate the process. It works great for me. Hope it helps you.

```
git init
git remote add origin new_repo
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push origin master
git remote add base base_repo
git checkout -b base
git pull base master
git checkout master
git merge base
git push origin master
git branch -d base
```

Comment: Your answer helps, but you missed that I only want the top of my repo.